# iOS How to know I'm crossing a particular location

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, core-location, compass-geolocation

I'm using Core Location with ios 6. I have been searching for this but could find an appropriate solution

My question is: - How can I know if I am crossing point X in any direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use distanceFromLocation method from CLLocation? 
Like:

```
 CLLocationDistance distance = [targetLocation distanceFromLocation:currLocation];
```

And in background you check the distance to see if the user is close enough to your point.

Comment: in which delegate method it should be called ?

Comment: You should add the code in 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    
}